# MySQL + PHP (grouping by date)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, group-by

I'm trying to output a list of different itmes grouped by the date they were stored in the database (**unix timestamp**).

I'd need help with both MySQL (query) and PHP (output).

**MySQL table**

id | subject | time
1  | test1   | 1280278800
2  | test2   | 1280278800
3  | test3   | 1280365200
4  | test4   | 1280451600
5  | test5   | 1280451600

**OUTPUT**

**Today**
test5
test4

**Yesterday**
test3

**July 28**
test2
test1

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks!;-)

Comment: A general tip is to not store dates as unix timestamps in MySQL, there is no reason to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert your unix timestamp to a date using `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))`. This will output something like `2010-07-30`.

The following should group by the date.

```
SELECT id, subject, time, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) AS date_column
GROUP BY date_column
```

**Edit:** Didn't read your question correctly.

For this I would just run a standard `SELECT` and `ORDER BY time DESC`.

Then do the grouping with PHP.

```
$lastDate = null;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $row['time']);
    $time = date('H:i', $row['time']);

    if (is_null($lastDate) || $lastDate !== $date) {
        echo "<h2>{$date}</h2>";
    }

    echo "{$time}<br />";

    $lastDate = $date;
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to Apply Paging (LIMIT) for this kind of Query ?

Answer (score 2):

you could create a mysql udf for that, something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `niceDate` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `niceDate` (ts INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) NO SQL
BEGIN

  declare dt DATETIME;
  declare ret VARCHAR(255);

  set dt = FROM_UNIXTIME(ts);

  IF DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%Y%m%d") = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y%m%d") THEN SET ret = 'Today';
  ELSEIF DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%Y%m%d") = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), "%Y%m%d") THEN SET ret = 'Yesterday';
  ELSE SET ret = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%M "), DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%d"));
  END IF;

  RETURN ret;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

You could then construct your query like this:
`select niceDate(your_date_field) from table group by niceDate(your_date_field) order by your_date_field desc`

disclaimer: i haven't tested this function, but you should get the idea.

Comment: This function doesn't take into account different years when input is neither today or yesterday, so 20100728 and 20090728 get grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to sort by timestamp (descending) in SQL, and do the grouping in PHP: Iterate over the result set, converting the timestamp to a DateTime object; when the current date is on a different day than the previous one (hint: use DateTime::format()), insert a sub-heading.